# How can view controllers in a tab controller know when it is being unwinded?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

My View hierarchy is like this:

```
Splash view -> "show" segue-> Tab Bar Controller (with 3 tabs)
```

That's it. Pretty simple application.

On the last tab,  I have a log out button.  When pushed, this log out button will perform an **unwind segue** back to the Splash View. (I'm guessing this destroys the tab controller and all its 3 views...but please let me know if I'm wrong).

So my question is:

How can my other 2 tabs know when an unwind segue is being called by the last tab? I need to remove observers and such before the user sees the splash page again.

Comment: @Rob is "addObserverForName" with a closure at the end considered a block based observer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to just unwind like normal, and let the normal deallocation process remove the observers for you. To do that, though, you must ensure you don't have a strong reference cycle.

Let's imagine that you had an observer that emptied a cache upon memory pressure. If you wanted to remove that observer when the object was deallocated, you'd use `unowned  self` reference:

```
let cache = NSCache()
var observer: NSObjectProtocol!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    observer = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { [unowned self] notification in
        self.cache.removeAllObjects()
    }
}
```

Then you could safely remove the observer in `deinit` without fear of strong reference cycle:

```
deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(observer)
}
```

You didn't share what you were observing, but it illustrates the idea: Break the strong reference cycle by using `[unowned self]` in the closure supplied to `addObserverForName`. For more information about `weak` and `unowned` references to `self` in closures, see [Resolving Strong Reference Cycles for Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID57) in *The Swift Programming Language.*

Comment: Can I put [unowned self] pretty much everywhere I have a closure? Just to be on the safe side?

Comment: No sometimes you want `[weak self]` (if it's possible for the object to be deallocated before the closure runs). A common example of that is a network request that you might reasonably expect to continue after the view controller is released. And sometimes you want strong reference (i.e., neither `unowned` nor `weak`).  You really should consider the object ownership structure that makes sense for the particular situation.

Answer (score 1):

In the Tab Bar Controller, during the `prepareForSegue:`, identify if the segue being performed is an unwind segue(You need to assign an identifier to the unwind segue).

After you have identified that the segue is an unwind segue, you can then inform the Controllers in the Tab Bar Controller that they should now remove observers and all needed processes.

Alternative: You can do it inside the `dealloc` method of each Controller of the Tab Bar Controller

Comment: My Tab Bar Controller doesn't have its own swift file (although the 3 controllers inside it have their own swift file).  Should it have its own swift file to check for prepareForSegue?

Comment: Yes. Or the alternative, you can do it during dealloc. When the Tab Bar Controller is popped from the view hierarchy, its view controllers will be deallocated

Comment: Why does it say that "dealloc" is marked unavailable? I've also tried deinit { } but that doesn't get called when I unwind from one of the tabs.

Comment: @TIMEX: That is weird. Probably has something to do with the Tab Bar Controller having a strong reference somewhere or one of its View Controllers.